# android webview calling javascript function after some time

Tags: android, timer, webview

```
  mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
  mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
  {
  mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){"+"document.getElementById('portable-banner-main_1').style.display ='none';"+"})()");
  }
  });
  WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
  webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
  mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
  mWebView.loadUrl(URL);
```

I am hiding an element with this. But page has a loading phase. So i need to run that javascript function like 5 seconds after onPageFinished. How can i do this?

Comment: can you tried with thread.sleep(5000) ...

Answer (score 4):

Use a Handler.

```
   private static int MY_SLEEP = 5000; // wait 5 seconds.

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
        final Handler handler=new Handler();        
        final Runnable r = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() 
            {
         mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){"+"document.getElementById('portable-banner-main_1').style.display ='none';"+"})()");
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(r, MY_SLEEP);

   }
 });
```